# Select one cell with a pasted range in Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba, onchange

I have a regular VBA `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` routine which is working fine except for when a user pastes a range of cells instead of changing an individual cell value.

Is there a way to discriminate between these two cases at the start of the routine so that:

1. A single cell change runs as normal
2. A pasted range will set
   `target` to the last cell in the range that has been changed (ie
   pasting A1:Z5 would select Z1) - before running the routine as
   normal

Comment: `If Target.Count > 1 Then`

Comment: Posting your code would probably be useful - changing `Target` is suspect here, as it isn't like `Cancel`.  The pasted changes have already taken place.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed :) @Comintern, thanks for pointing out the warning on the changes haven taken place however my code iterates over each column anyway so it wasn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple option:

A1:Z5 would select Z5:

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Set Target = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, Target.Columns.Count)
End If
```

A1:Z5 would select Z1:

```
If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Set Target = Target.Cells(1, Target.Columns.Count)
End If
```

Comment: as per OP's example that should be `Set Target = Target.Cells(1, Target.Columns.Count)`

Comment: @user3598756 I've amended my answer.  However, when I read "last changed cell", I tend to assume bottom right, not top right...

Comment: @Christmas007, Agree